# Is a reduction or atomic operation on mat/vec types with OpenGL compute shader possible?

Tags: opengl-es, atomic, compute-shader

Is it possible to do reduction/update or atomic operations in the computer shader on e.g. `mat3`, `vec3` data types?

Like this scheme:

```
some_type mat3 A;
void main() {
    A += mat3(1);
}
```

I have tried out to use shader storage buffer objects (`SSBO`) but it seems like the update is not atomic (at least I get wrong results when I read back the buffer).

Does anyone have an idea to realize this? Maybe creating a tiny 3x3 `image2D` and store the result by `imageAtomicAdd` in there?

Comment: You need some kind of synchronization. See e.g. [here](http://diaryofagraphicsprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/03/compute-shader-optimizations-for-amd.html) or [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2010/presentations/S12312-DirectCompute-Pre-Conference-Tutorial.pdf).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you for the links. I forgot to mention that I work with ARM Mali GPUs und as such they do not expose TLP and do not have warps/wave fronts as Nvidia or AMD. That is, I might have to figure out another quick way.

Comment: Did you even try and look in GLES 3.1 spec for atomics? It's not like they are easy to miss - they are even in the table of contents ... (Section 7.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are buffer-based atomics in GLES 3.1.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.1/es_spec_3.1.pdf

Section 7.7.

> Maybe creating a tiny 3x3 image2D and store the result by imageAtomicAdd in there?

Image atomics are not core and require an extension.

> Thank you for the links. I forgot to mention that I work with ARM Mali GPUs and as such they do not expose TLP and do not have warps/wave fronts as Nvidia or AMD. That is, I might have to figure out another quick way.

The techniques proposed in the comments for your post (in particular the log(N) divisor approach where you fold the top half of the results down) still work fine on Mali. The technique doesn't rely on warps/wavefronts - as the original poster said, you just need synchronization (e.g. use a `barrier()` rather than relying on the implicit barrier which wavefronts would give you).

Comment: Indeed @NicoSchertler asnwer is correct , it works fine too. Implemented it just 5 mins ago. Thanks.

Note: You suggestion to use atomics works with ```uint```/```int``` data types only. But it turned out, ```imageAtomicAdd``` as well.